# What is the product of results of this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to get product of results by $x$?

$$(25+x)^{1/3} + (3-x)^{1/3} = 4$$

I have tried to to get both sides on cube but I got nothing.

Comment: we get $x=-24$ or $x=2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(25+x)^{1/3}=u$, $(3-x)^{1/3}=v$. We have a system:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u + v &= 4\\
u^3 + v^3 &= 28
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$u^3+v^3=(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2) = (u+v)\bigl((u+v)^2 - 3uv\bigr)\Longrightarrow uv=3$.
If $u+v=4$ and $uv=3$, then $u=1, v=3$ (and $x=-24$) or $u=3,v=1$ (and $x=2$).

Comment: At the end I have put this product(u*v=3) on cube and got the product of x1 and x2 with Viete formulas thanks.

Answer (score 2):

or use this well konwn:
if $$a+b+c=0\Longrightarrow a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$$
where
$$a=\sqrt[3]{25+x},b=\sqrt[3]{3-x},c=-4$$
then we have
$$25+x+3-x-64=-12\sqrt[3]{-x^2-22x+75}$$
so
$$-x^2-22x+75=27\Longrightarrow x=2,\rm{or}-24$$